# Rails 4 Carrierwave, post updating isn't working correctly after implementing multiple uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I implemented multiple uploads with Carrierwave and I'm unable to update my post correctly. Here is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_posts, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :home]

    def home
    end

    def index
        if params[:category].blank?
            @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
        else
            @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id  
            @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")


        end
    end

    def show
        @inquiries = Inquiry.where(post_id: @post).order("created_at DESC")
        @random_post = Post.where.not(id: @post).order("RANDOM()").first
        @post_attachments = @post.post_attachments.all

    end

    def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
        @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.build
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            if @post.save 
                params[:post_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
                    @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:image => a)
                end
                format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
            else 
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
            end
        end
    end

    def update
      if @post.update(post_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Post successfully updated!"
        redirect_to @post
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong...give it another shot!"
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def edit
    end



    def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

    def upvote
        @post.upvote_by current_user
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def downvote
        @post.downvote_by current_user
        redirect_to @post
    end

    private 
    def find_posts 
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :price, :description, :location, :category_name, :contact_number, :image)
    end
end
```

Basically, the post is creating just fine, but when I attempt to update the images, the new images doesn't replace the old ones. I'm not sure how to go about changing my update to have it accept new images. NOTE: Other fields work when I update, just not my images.

What do I change in my controller to make it work? If you need to see my form or anything else, let me know, but I'm quite certain it's in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said creating a post is working fine. But updating a post is not. Then after looking at your code, it seems as I expected, that your `def update` is missing some code that you have in your `def create` specifically the `params[:post_attachments]['image']` part.

Just in case you do not know yet, `def create` is called when you click the submit button in the new-post form, while `def update` is called  when you click the submit button in the edit-post form.

Comment: I know that and I'm not quite sure how to add that to the current code

Comment: Are you using form_for in your view file? or form_tag? In [carrierwave github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#user-content-multiple-file-uploads) it says there to use `<%= form.file_field :avatars, multiple: true %>` in which I would expect in your form you'll have something like `<%= f.file_field :attachments, multiple: true %>`. But if you didn't follow their multiple-file upload convention and created another table `post_attachments`, you would then need to change your view files to include :id and so that you could update those specific attachments.

Comment: I will update my answer in possible changes to your controller when I am free later.

Comment: I don't think I have an id for the individual images yet, I just sort of hacked it together